# How to keep uploaded file or attachment on server directory contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a blog where I am using contact form 7. But I need these info to save into db and want to show in user profile with attachment also. As cf7 upload images or attachment temporary in wpcf_upload folders.
I can save all data in custom table by this:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_application_form');
```

So first i have to keep images or attachment of cf7 permanently on server.

So please tell me how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create your own **custom post typ**e to handle user profile, and then create a ***side bar widget*** or something to submit the data,

But if you want to save ***wpcf7*** data, insert the below code inside your **function.php** file,

Make sure you create your **custom table**,

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_application_form' );

function save_application_form($wpcf7)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ($submission) {
        $submited = array();
        $submited['title'] = $wpcf7->title();
        $submited['posted_data'] = $submission->get_posted_data();
    }
    $data = array(
        'name' => $submited['posted_data']['name'],
        'email' => $submited['posted_data']['email']
    );
    $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . 'your_table_name', array(
        'form' => $submited['title'],
        'data' => serialize($data) ,
        'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks jlocker, but my question is how to keep attached file or image on server permanently. i already done form submission into db.

Comment: @jlocker but how do you save it with a custom name on your server? $submission->uploaded_files() only gives me the temp path to the file uploaded

Answer (score 15):

Here's [a link](http://chamankumar.co.uk/blog/uncategorized/contact-form-7-add-uploaded-file-to-media-attach-to-custom-post).

I simplified the code from the link above. Maybe it helps:

```
 function cf7_create_post($data) {
    //In case you wanna check for a especific form
    /* $form_id = $data->id;
      if ($form_id != '1234')
      return;/* */

    //Get the current posted form instance
    $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ($form_to_DB) {
        $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data(); // Get all data from the posted form
        $uploaded_files = $form_to_DB->uploaded_files(); // this allows you access to the upload file in the temp location
    }

    // Let's insert the new post first to get the ID.
    $newpostid = wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'post_title' => "Your new Post Title", // Can be  $formData['YOUR-CF7-FIELD-NAME']
        'post_type' => "post", //Post Type
        'post_content' => "Your new Post Content", // Can be  $formData['YOUR-CF7-FIELD-NAME']
    ));


    // We need to get the CF7 field name from FILE
    $cf7_file_field_name = 'uploadyourfile'; // [file uploadyourfile]

    //Do the magic the same as the refer link above
    $image_name = $formData[$cf7_file_field_name];
    $image_location = $uploaded_files[$cf7_file_field_name];
    $image_content = file_get_contents($image_location);
    $wud = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload = wp_upload_bits($image_name, null, $image_content);
    $chemin_final = $upload['url'];
    $filename = $upload['file'];
    if ($filename > '') {
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null);
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
            'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $filename, $newpostid);
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $filename);
        wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
        //Define the new Thumbnail can be also a ACF field
        update_post_meta($newpostid, "_thumbnail_id", $attach_id);
    }
}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'cf7_create_post',1);//added to functions.php
```

All credits go to the link above, I just changed a bit. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Tunaki =)

Comment: Is this possible just to update ACF img field in users?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the uploaded files in server by installing "[Contact Form Submissions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-submissions/)" plugin. The uploaded files will be saved to "wp-content/uploads/wpcf7-submissions/".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code (or use the plugin) [Store file uploads for Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/store-file-uploads-for-contact-form-7/) - it stores file attachments into Media Library