# Save Attachment Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm working in WordPress with Contact Form 7. I'm dynamically creating a Word Document based on the users submitted data, and I want to save that file to the server that the user is sent from Contact Form 7.

But i can not see the files anywhere. Where i am wrong?

I have the following code at the moment:

```
<h3 class="anchor">PLEASE UPLOAD COPIES OF YOUR MEDICAL CARD AND CDL . </h3>
<label> Here is my medical card:
    [file step_2_medical_card_upl filetypes:doc|docx|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png] </label>

<label> Here is my CDL:
    [file step_2_cdl_upl filetypes:doc|docx|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png] </label>
```

and in mail tab i added `[step_2_medical_card_upl]` and `[step_2_cdl_upl]` . The files are in email, but not in server. How to save them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep uploaded file or attachment on server directory contact form 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804191/how-to-keep-uploaded-file-or-attachment-on-server-directory-contact-form-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Form 7 moves the uploaded file to a temporary folder. At this point, Contact Form 7 attaches the file to the mail and sends it. After these procedures, Contact Form 7 then removes the file from the temporary folder.

Ref: https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/

It calls `remove_uploaded_files()` after procedures which have no filter to stop it. So apparently what you want here, isn't meant to be done by the author of CF7.

Comment: You can ask the developer to include a way to make this possible. E.g. here: wordpress.org/support/plugin/contact-form-7

Comment: yes, i know for temporary files, but i think they can copy to other place, before delete it

Comment: They are not doing the same for now, so you can use contact form 7 database plugin OR comment the function calling `remove_uploaded_files()` (not a good way) OR ask in support to add a way.

Answer (score 0):

You could install this plugin: [Store file uploads for Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/store-file-uploads-for-contact-form-7/).
It will save all files uploaded using CF7 `[file ...]` into Media Library.
It works by intercepting *CF7 action*:

```
wpcf7_before_send_mail
```